# Strange background image and borders bug on Iphone

Tags: css, iphone, background, background-image, border

**!UPDATE** just got this bug on the bigger element. guess its not related to SVG but to background and borders. Heres the pic:

[image]

so it seems like borders are behind the background. Strange thing is that the next photo (the cut one at the bottom) is rendered by the same react component. More strangely, after around 5 seconds bug disappeared. Maybe some server issues? Im freaking stuck...=(

**!UPDATE** Browserstack do not show this bug on my setup. But me and my friend see them still on real phones...

Got this bug on iphone (on Safari and Chrome). Some white (sometimes black) background underneath the svg or something. I look at the pic and do not know whats going on really =(

[image]

The SVG is perfectly transparent. There are no problems on desktop browsers. The bug shows itself randomly, it may be seen at first, but after some interactions, it disappears, or if you reload the page it can disappear. Strange thing really.

I would appreciate if anybody tells me what is wrong with it.

Here is the jss code of this circle...

```
  filter: {
    width: 64,
    height: 64,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 11,
    right: 15,
    transition: 'transform 0.2s ease-out',
    '&:hover': {
      transform: 'scale(1.2)',
      transformOrigin: 'center',
    },
    cursor: 'pointer',
    outline: 'none',
  },

  filter0: {
    extend: 'filter',
    backgroundImage: `url(${sun})`,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    backgroundPosition: 'center',
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
    backgroundSize: '48px',
    borderRadius: 32,
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
    border: `5px solid ${tastes[0].color}`,
  },
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok. This is not the full answer, but...

The problem is showing only while network throttling on Safari on Iphone on the speed of 300kbps. I think that this is just the way browser renders the stuff with background and borders. While network throttling it is seen quite good that while loading the "bug" appears and after some time it disappears. If some bugs stay they disappear after starting to scroll in any direction.

I hope that it's not my poor implementation but some browser rendering algorithm for such elements on a slow loading speed. I also done some refactoring to speed things up, so the problem is not seen now on an average 3g connection.

You can view the bug on video here - [bug video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_kw0DhGVu8M&feature=youtu.be)